# jQuery's $.each function repeatedly adding val of first item only

Tags: jquery, arrays

I’m trying to use jQuery’s Each function to iterate over 3 text inputs  and put each one’s value into an array. My code below is not working. Instead it is adding the value of the first input only and doing so 3 times. So the resulting array is:
    players = [‘Bob’, ‘Bob’, ‘Bob’]

instead of: 
    players = [‘Bob’, ‘Tom’,     ‘Ziggy’];

I know it has something to do w the index not being applied per input item but don’t know how to remedy this.

The markup is this:

```
<input type="text" class="player" id="player1" value="Bob" /><br>
<input type="text" class="player" id="player2" value="Tom" /><br>
<input type="text" class="player" id="player3" value="Ziggy" /><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
```

Js is this:

```
var players = [];

$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.each($('input.player'), function(index){
    var pName = $('input.player').val();
    //var pName = index.val(); tried this too
        players.push(pName);
        console.log(index);
        console.log(players);

    });
```

Comment: where's your HTML?

Comment: That is not correct usage of `$.each`, you want `$('input.player').each(function() {var pName = this.value; ... });`

Comment: Please provide a full example (your html is missing) so people can more easily help you. Preferably make a snippet or jsfiddle showing how your code works wrong.

Comment: @jonju Right there. It's just that OP forgot an empty line before a code block so it wasn't rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within `.each()`, you need to use `$(this)` to access the current element:

```
var players = [];

$('#submit').click(function(){
  $.each($('input.player'), function(index){
    var pName = $(this).val();
    players.push(pName);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(players);
  });
});
```

Note that this is equivalent to your `.each()` function, and IMO easier to read:

```
$('input.player').each(function(index){
    var pName = $(this).val();
    players.push(pName);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(players);
});
```

According to Ozan:

> You could also use the second parameter of the callback function of $.each()

And the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each) agree:

> Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )

```
$('input.player').each(function(index, element){
    var pName = $(element).val(); // Note the changed line here
    players.push(pName);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(players);
});
```

Comment: You could also use the `second parameter` of the `callback function` of `.each()`

Comment: @Ozan Didn't know that! Shall add it in :)

Comment: If using the 2nd parameter, you need to wrap `element` within a jQuery wrapper, like so before you can access jQuery functions `$(element).val()` is what it should be.  Otherwise, should be able to use `element.value` instead.

Comment: @SolomonClosson Thanks for the correction - just found out about this!

Comment: Another alternative: you could use `.eq()` with the `index` like this : `var pName = $('input.player').eq(index).val();` But the use of `$(this)` is more concise. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I would argue it's more performant too, but that's creative :p

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette That also introduces complications if you were to modify the elements in any way - for instance removing the `player` class after having processed them. Doesn't really apply here but as a general your suggestion would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore everything else, just focus on the line that's apparently the problem:

```
var pName = $('input.player').val();
```

What does this line do? It gives you the value of the first `'input.player'` element (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)).

And, funnily enough, this is exactly the result you see: the value of the first input over and over again.

Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do, but that is not what you meant.

Within a `.each` loop, the keyword `this` refers to the current element in the loop. Since it's a raw DOM node and not a jQuery object, you will need to wrap it as `$(this)`... but since you are only getting its value, the [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) version `this.value` will work far more efficiently.

See Nick Bull's answer for actual code, I just wanted to outline how to approach debugging code yourself.